# why c++ use CustomClass** instead CustomClass* to create function that return list of CustomClass pointer?

Tags: c++

so i am learning basic of c++ and i have this custom class

```
class DataBook{
private:
    vector<PersonData> dataList;
    PersonData* numList[10];
    PersonData* nameList[10];
public:
PersonData** getNumList(){
    return this->numList;
    }
```

i just cant understand why we use `PersonData**` instead of `PersonData*`.
i know it should be `PersonData**` because error reporting says so. but i can't understand the logic behind this reason. thanks!

Comment: Basically, when handling static arrays, you are really handling *pointers to the first element of the array*. I guess this should clear-up the misunderstanding

Comment: If you're using pointers rather than references, you're not *really* doing C++ :-)

Comment: This is just bad programming really. You should not do this in your own code but it can be useful to recognize bad idioms other people might use

Comment: @M.M can you answer a good style of my code? so i can learn from you. thanks!

Comment: use `std::array<PersonData, 10>` and either return by value or reference depending on what behaviour you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass (or return) an array, what actually gets through is a *pointer to the first element* of said array.

And, since you have an array of `PersonData*` elements, a pointer to the first element of *that* array is of the type `PersonData**`.

That should hopefully answer your immediate question.

---

However, I'd also like to take the opportunity of warn you about becoming a C+ programmer, that strange breed who seem to write C code in C++ :-)

Although C++ is originally *based* on C, it's often said (well, *I* say it quite a bit) that the *hardest* people to teach C++ to are C developers.

If someone wants to be a C++ developer, they should try to fully embrace the C++ "mindset", including consideration of the following points relevant to your code:

- If you're passing pointers around that will always refer to an actual item (rather than possibly being `NULL`/`nullptr`), you're almost certainly doing it wrong. This is the whole reason references were created and I long for the days that they're introduced into C, even if only to do pass-by-reference in function calls.
- If you hide your data behind the private section of a class, it's probably a *bad* idea to expose it to arbitrary modification with a public API. Your attempted protection of `numList` is rather irrelevant when I could just do `auto x = obj.GetNumList(); x[0] = nullptr;`. If you must do it that way, you should at *least* return a pointer to `const` to clearly indicate it shouldn't be modified.
- You should even consider replacing your base-level arrays with `std::vector` or `std::array` since both of those provide protections against modifying out-of-range elements and also pass around the size information *with* the object, something you don't get with raw pointers.

Answer (score 0):

In your `getNumList()` function you want to return an array of pointers.
The propery way of returning an array of functions in C++ is returning a pointer to the first element (usually).

Therefore, an **array of pointers** becomes **a pointer to a pointer** (the first element).

Think of when you have an array of integers:

```
int *return_array(int ray[2])
{
    return ray; // OR return &ray OR return &ray[0]
}
```

Now assuming instead of integers we have integer pointer this will become:

```
int **return_array(int *ray[2])
{
    return ray; // OR return &ray OR return &ray[0]
}
```

Comment: `int` return type and returning the address of an int array? I'm not sure I'm linking this.

Comment: @N00byEdge Whoops, that's a typo. Thanks for the note.

Comment: If you call your array `ray`, what do you call your class? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo lass